# Can I distinguish between post flags and comment flags in my flagging history?

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags, flag-history

When I am looking at [my flagging history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current), I can choose to display only post flags, only comment flags, only spam flags or only rude/abusive flags.

Even when I view the whole flagging history, I can see which flags are spam flags and which are rude/abusive flags, since they have a description in the minor red box.

For other flags (not spam/rude), is there some way how can I see whether it is post flag or comment flag (when displaying all flags)? I mean some way to do this other than choosing to display only one type of flags and checking whether this specific flag is still in the list.

Comment: I think your best shot is SEDE, though I’m not sure flagging history is in there.

Comment: @DanBron: no, flags are not part of the SEDE dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort-of possible, except for custom moderator flags. For standard flags, the 'name' of the flag is displayed:

[image]

'not an answer' and 'very low quality' are obviously post flags, as are 'off-topic', 'too broad' and 'primarily opinion-based'. Comment flags will show their name as well, e.g. 'no longer needed'.

If you raise a custom moderator flag, the text you typed in the box will be shown, so it will be a bit harder to determine if that was a comment or post flag. Another reason to be as clear as possible in those custom flag messages :)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I have raised some "custom" flags (with the text filled in by me) - which is why I was unsure when looking at the list of flags how to distinguish (just from the list) whether it was a comment flag or a post flag.

Comment: This used to be much harder back when "not constructive" was both a close reason and a comment flag reason.